# Should I negate a variable or use absolute value?

Tags: mathematics, collision-resolution, linear-algebra

this is how i was chaning ball postion

```
if(...) //if ball goes to left of screen
  dx = -dx
if(...) //if ball goes right of screen
  dx = -dx;
```

i found some people using math.abs to move ball postion.

```
if(...)  //if ball goes to left of screen
    dx = Math.abs(dx);
if(...) //if ball goes right of screen
    dx = -Math.abs(dx);
```

which is better? if 2nd one than plz explain why.

Comment: What does this have to do with Gimbal-lock?

Comment: It has nothing to do with gimbal lock.  @newbi Please try to find appropriate tags for your questions.  This one has no more to do with the question than point-clouds had to do with your last question about a breakout clone.

Answer (score 3):

Neither is better.  They are different functions.  Their appropriateness is determined by what you are trying to do.

```
//negate a variable
dx = -dx;

//force a variable to be positive or negative
dx = Math.Abs(dx);
dx = -Math.Abs(dx);
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the circumstances in some physics engines it may happen that two objects that overlap in one frame, and has their collision resolved, still overlap in the next frame. If they therefore have their collision resolved again it will typically reverse the original collision, resulting in the objects getting stuck together as they spend every second frame moving towards one another and every other frame moving equally away from one another.

The `abs` code is a simple fix for this, ensuring that the collision will only happen if the ball is moving towards the wall.